# How can I get Lambda and API gateway to output just my "hits" number from DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

A simple questions but I can't seem to get my head around it. How can I get Lambda and API gateway to output just my "hits" number. Of course the hits number will continue to change. So I would like to see the code below instead of the whole response I am getting now:

```
{
"hits":58
}
```

Here is my Lambda function:

```
import json
import boto3

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
client = dynamodb.Table('hitcounter')
table = dynamodb.Table('hitcounter')

def lambda_handler(event, context):


    update = client.update_item(
        TableName='hitcounter',
        Key={
            'path': 'me'
        },
        UpdateExpression='ADD hits :incr',
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':incr': 1}
    )

    response = table.get_item(
        Key={
            'path': 'me'
        }
    )   

    return{

        'body' : response
    }
```

Here is the response I get:

```
{
  "body": {
    "Item": {
      "path": "me",
      "hits": 58
    },
    "ResponseMetadata": {
      "RequestId": "4C5981CHPI35FDB8F7Q83K7TP7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
      "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
      "HTTPHeaders": {
        "server": "Server",
        "date": "Thu, 11 Jun 2020 22:32:34 GMT",
        "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.0",
        "content-length": "46",
        "connection": "keep-alive",
        "x-amzn-requestid": "4C5981CHPI35FDB8F7Q83K7TP7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG",
        "x-amz-crc32": "3034993695"
      },
      "RetryAttempts": 0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```py
'body' : response
```

With:

```py
'body' : response['Item']['hits']
```

Comment: This delivers this error message:
```
{
  "errorMessage": "'body'",
  "errorType": "KeyError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 28, in lambda_handler\n    'body' : response['body']['Item']['hits']\n"
  ]
}

```

Comment: Changed it to this and worked great. Thanks so much!

'body' : response['Item']['hits']

Comment: Updated answer to match. Thanks!